# Search specified text in text area - jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

I have a text area with HTML content,now i want to search there for specified text,if text area contains the text i need to return TRUE or FALSE.

also is there any way to check that a specified DOM is on that TEXT AREA [WITH HTML CONTENT] ?

Ex :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body background="" bgcolor="red">
</body>
</html>
```

So now i want to check that the BODY tag have Background or bgcolor,if it contains i need to return true,how can i do this ?
Actually i am trying to build a UI for editing HTML,if the html area contain

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **indexOf**, see the following example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mikhailov/S5jaz/2/

**html**

```
<textarea id="txt">
  Here I am
</textarea>
```

**JS**

```
var txt = $('#txt').val();
var word1 = txt.indexOf('Heref') != -1;    // false
var word2 = txt.indexOf('Here I') != -1;   // true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = $('#textarea').val();
var regex = /.../;
var found = text.match(regex);
if (found != null){return 1}
```